# Why does Firefox react differently from Webkit and IE to "click" event on "select" tag?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, firefox, webkit

I realized Firefox treats *click* event on `<select>` tag differently from Webkit/IE, and I couldn't figure out why or how to resolve this difference.

Specifically, Webkit/IE regards each *click* event on `<select>`  as a combination of **both** clicking on "select", **and** the clicking of one of the drop-down `<option>`, shown in graphs below:

First Click:

[image: First click]

Second Click:

[image: Second click]

In Webkit/IE, *click* event will be fired only after both clicks have been done.

However, in Firefox, the first click on the `<select>` tag is regarded as a *click* event, the second click to select `<option>` is regarded as another *click* event. Therefore, **two** *click* events have been fired in Firefox comparing to **one** in Webkit/IE for the same operation.

Now to demonstrate it in code example, assuming we have: ([JSfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/SBZD8/))

```
<select id="sel">
    <option>one</option>
    <option>two</option>
    <option>three</option>​
</select>
<script>
function select() {
    $("#sel").one("click", function(event) {
        console.log('mouse down!');
        $("#sel").one('click', function() {
            console.log('mouse down again!');
            $("#sel").off();
            select();
        });
    });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    select();
});
</script>
```

In Webkit/IE, performing the set of operations shown above in the graph (for the first time) will give output:

```
mouse down!
```

In Firefox, it will give:

```
mouse down!
mouse down again!
```

Why is it so and how do I fix it?

Edit: I tried with pure JavaScript without jQuery, the result remains the same.

Edit 2: A little more context, I originally answered this question: [onclick on option tag not working on IE and chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972280/onclick-on-option-tag-not-working-on-ie-and-chrome/10058960#10058960) and won a bounty for my answer. However, as the op later pointed out, my solution did not work on Firefox. I decided to dig deeper to resolve this problem, and hence this question was asked and I am rewarding that 50 bounty I got from that solution. Essentially, the problem is to create a select menu that will trigger an event whenever a selection is made, even when it is the same. This has proven to be harder than expected, if possible at all due to different browser implementations.

Edit 3: I am fully aware of `onchange`, but the question here is not about `onchange` if you read carefully. I need to have each selection trigger an event *even if* they are the same selection (which will not trigger `onchange`.

Comment: Arent you just looking for the Selected event?

Comment: I get "mouse down mouse down again" in Opera, Firefox (latest trunk), Chrome and IE on Win7 x64.

Comment: @Shadow2531 Which version of Opera are you using? Opera 11.62 only returns `mouse down`, same as Safari 5.1.5 and Chrome on OS X 10.7

Comment: @KayZhu I'm using Opera 11.62 Final and Opera 12.00.1328 on Win7 x64.

Comment: @Shadow2531 Interesting, that means they behave differently in OS X and Win7.

Comment: I'm actually getting "mouse down" in both browsers. FF 11.0 and Chrome 20.0.1096.1 dev-m on Win 7 x64.

Answer (score 9):

Why not work with `onchange` event?

```
$("#sel").change(function(){
    $('body').append("<br/> Option changed");
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/juzerali/j2WwY/3/)

But it won't fire an even when selection is the same. Work around is to use a plugin like Chosen as suggested in another answer.

EDIT: Philosophically speaking `select` element is not meant for such functionality. `change` event suffices for most use cases related to `select` tags. The functionality that you desire, that is to know if a user has made a selection over the element (even if it hasn't change), doesn't fit the functional model of the `select` tag. Logically nobody would want to click on a `select` element if he/she doesn't want to change the selection.

To fit your requirement, you can give a **Go** `button` besides your select tag and call the same function `onclick` that you would normally do with the `onchange` event of `select` element. Otherwise give a **hovercard/hover-menu**  instead of `select`.

Comment: onchange is a good start, but it will fire too often, if you select with the keyboard. Maybe your plugin credits this. Do you know about this?

Comment: @yunzen It won't fire too often with keyboard. It will fire only after you press `enter` on the selected option. You can try that with given fiddle link.

Comment: Thanks for the input. But my question isn't about `onchange` at all -- you answered your own question it will not fire an event when selection is the same. My question only about why this discrepancy occurs in different browsers for `onchange` and how to make it go away while using it.

Comment: @juzerali There are two types of keyboard access to a select field. First how you mean: Click on it --> It folds out, then use the keyboard and press enter. But second for the disabled: Focus on the select with the tab key, --> It won't fold out; then use the keyboard --> It will always fire onchange

Comment: @yunzen Okay, never heard of it.

Comment: Since the Question is about the click event I don't have an answer.  But the Solution to the question is to use the correct event.  Which probably is onchange.  As @juzerali wrote.  On an academic note: is the click event specified exactly in ecmascript? - hmm.  That might be the Answer to your question: "it isn't specified".

Comment: @LosManos With all due respect, my question has stated clearly that `onchange` is not an option at all, since the desired effect needs to get triggered even if the selection is the **same**, i.e., not changed. Thank you for your lead though, I probably should have looked into the ECMAScript spec for definition much earlier. My guess is that you are right in that this behaviour is probably vaguely defined and interpreted differently among different browsers.

Comment: The fiddle does not work for me on FF on OSx. The options show but clicking one does not do anything. The options list never goes away and no change event is triggered. If I use the keyboard and press enter it does change. It does work in FF on Windows.

Comment: Seems like this must be an issue with FF on OSx and jsFiddle. The [example on mozilla's site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/select) does work, but the same HTML copied into jsFiddle does not work.

Answer (score 4):

After many experiments and searching, I am starting to get convinced that this particular different behaviour in different browsers is hard to resolve, if possible at all.

I realized, however, I could solve the problem from the other side, by using [jQuery UI select menu](http://view.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/demos/selectmenu/default.html) or [Chosen](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen) to create a select menu instead of using `<select>` tag. This way `click` event will be fired on `<ul>` or `<li>` tag which is consistent in all browsers I tested.

Comment: I think the answer IS--due to different JavaScript engines and implementations--that behavior will not be the same on these different browsers with the `click` event, and the "solution" is to change the HTML (like you said here) or change the JavaScript event (like juzerali said).

Comment: I think the difference is in Chrome, you're clicking a faux option list, and in Firefox, you're actually clicking the option element. Have you tried anything with `if(!$(event.target).is('option')) ...;`?

Comment: @Kay Zhu - I was unable to reproduce the problem in FF11 on W7 x64.  However, have you tried using event.stopPropagation() in your event bind?  I'm wondering if its actually an issue of event bubbling due to the way the select box is being rendered.

Comment: @kmfk Thanks, yes I indeed have tried `event.stopPropagation` during my experiments, but it didn't help either..

Comment: Thanks! I faced the same problem and I ended up using [Chosen](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen) which turned to be even nicer than a regular `select`. It's better to use native controls as per usability matters but design is more important for me at this point.

Answer (score 2):

> Essentially, the problem is to create a select menu that will trigger an event whenever a selection is made, even when it is the same.

This *technically* does (sorta) that, but in FF it triggers when you click to open and when you click to close (which you can actually do in one click, which produces the exact same thing in Safari AND Firefox). But it *is* the same event. (A click trigger fire on `$('#sel')`);

```
$("#sel").click(function(event) {
    if($(event.target).is('option')) {
        $(this).closest('select').click();
        return true;
    }
    console.log(event.target);
});
```

The reason I say that it "sorta" does that, is it doesn't handle if you select the dropdown from tabbing over and using the arrow keys. I think that if you are needing the event to be triggered even if the event same item is selected, you need to go about this differently. For me as a developer, if this was my project, it'd be unacceptable that if I tab to a select box and choose an item without touching the mouse, it won't work (meaning if a user comes to my site and interacts with a select box without a mouse and it doesn't do something he doesn't even know it's supposed to do, possibly making the whole thing not work, etc).

We can play around all day with getting `.click()` to work, but it's not really the solution, even if we achieved the original goal. (Oh, and I could never get **anything** to fire in Chrome).

Like I said in my comment, I think it has to do with how they handle interactions with the select. It almost feels as though Safari's select isn't actually on the page... that it sort creates this pretty element that acts and looks like a list of `<option>` elements when you click on it, but it isn't. Probably why it doesn't fire when you first click it either. Webkit doesn't treat it as a "real" element when you click on it, and just fires click on the select when you close it, never having interacted with the "real" options.

Changing the HTML may be the only way to go (like Chosen does). Ironically, some of the Chosen elements (the ones that look like dropdowns) can't be selected by tabbing over... at least not on their [demo page](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) (see the "Standard Select"). But that at least forces me to click on it, so it triggers mouse-related events.

Anyway, I hate unsolved problems, but it looks like there's no real solution for getting `.click()` to work on a `<select>` in all browsers and we should start focusing on alternative solutions. Sorry :-(