# jQuery click event not firing on optgroup

Tags: jquery

I have the following code - [example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NWDC8/1/)

```
<select>
 <optgroup label="Group1">
   <option value="11">Option 1</option>
   <option value="12">Option 2</option>
 </optgroup>
 <optgroup label="Group2">
   <option value="21">Option 1</option>
   <option value="22">Option 2</option>
 </optgroup>
</select>​
```

and some jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("select optgroup").click(function() {
    alert("Clicked " + $(this).attr("label"));            
});
```

This seems pretty straight forward.  If I add `onclick="javascript:alert(...);"` that seems to work ... except that the click fires no matter what is clicked.

Why doesn't this work?

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT**

It seems there is a misunderstanding in what I'm trying to do here so I need to expand the code a bit to give a better idea.

What I'm shooting for is to be able to do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("select optgroup").children().hide();
   $("select optgroup").click(function() {
      $(this).children().show();
   });
```

As you can see, trapping a click event on the option and then determining the group won't work because the options will all be hidden.  I want the options displayed when you click the Group (optgroup).  Having said that, Chrome doesn't seem to respect a click on the group and IE only returns the group of the selected item (when you click an optgroup) item.

Comment: What are you adding the onclick="etc." to? What do you want the click to be specific to?

Comment: Okay, I'm noticing that it "somewhat" seems to work in IE but doesn't in Chrome.  I say "somewhat" because what I really want is to click the Group not select an option.

Comment: The ultimate desired effect is to create an accordion effect where clicking on the group expands the group and displays the options while hiding the options of the other groups.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119793/why-does-firefox-react-differently-from-webkit-and-ie-to-click-event-on-selec/10160297#10160297

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So the short answer on this seems to be that this is not possible.  It is not possible to take a normal select with optionGroups and turn it into an accordion styled select list where initially, only the optiongroup items are displayed and clicking an optiongroup item expands its children (the options).

It seems that no browsers truly support clicking a group item in the select list.  While there is an onClick event, the event acts more like you've clicked the selected item.

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("select").change(function() {
        var clicked = $(this)
                         .find('option:selected') // get selected option
                         .parent()   // get that option's optgroup
                         .attr("label");   // get optgroup's label

        alert( clicked );
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NWDC8/5/)**

#### Note

`.click()` is wrong event you're using. see [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11565864/jquery-click-event-not-firing-on-optgroup/11565895#comment15299624_11565895)

Comment: Only in firefox, yours works in chrome as well. The `"click"` is wrong event to use here, so +1 for using `"change"`

Comment: using you code I realized what he was trying to do.. amazing that you where able to understand.

Comment: Actually, this code doesn't do what I want.  I want to actually be able to click the Group (optgroup) not the option.  See my "ultimate desired effect" above.

Answer (score 0):

There is one sophisticated solution that allows you to listen click events on optgroups in multiple select. The idea is listen clicks at the parent select item and calculate if user has clicked at the optgroup title.

```
$('#multipleSelectId').click(function(event) {
    var y = event.pageY - $(this).offset().top;
    var row = Math.floor((y - 4) / 15);
    $(this).find('optgroup').each(function() {
        if (row == 0) {
            onOptgroupClick($(this));       
            return false;
        }
        row -= $(this).children().length + 1; 
    });
});
```

This approach has been tested in Chromium 30, Firefox 25, IE 9.

I don't know whether it can be applied to single selects, but with "multiple=multiple" it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can solve it using jQuery.

First assign the event to the optgroup, and see if propagation was stopped.

```
$('optgroup').on('click',function(e) {
    if(!e.isPropagationStopped()){
        if ($(this).find('option:visible').length == $(this).children().length) {
            $(this).children().hide();
        }
        else {
            $(this).children().show();
        }
    }
});
```

Next up, we want to prevent the previous piece of code to trigger when we click one of the child options.

```
$('optgroup > option').on('click',function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent().trigger('change');
});
```

The "trigger" event that is called at the end of the function is to ensure that any other assigned triggers on the change event are still triggered.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select>
<optgroup onclick="$(this).children().toggle();">
<option>Item 1</option>
<option>Item 2</option>
<option>Item 3</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
<script>
    $( "option" ).click(function( event ) {
      event.stopPropagation();
    }); 
</script>
```