# jQuery How to trigger a certain option of a select

Tags: jquery, events, html-select

I want to do some things when certain option is selected, how I can define that?
Here is an example:

```
<select id="mySelect">
   <option>...</option>
   ...
   <option>...</option>
   <option id="myOption">I need exactly this option</option>
</select>
```

How I can do it? I made like this:

```
$('#city').change(function(){
 if($("#another_city", this).is(":selected")){
        alert('ok');
     }
});
```

I want to see how I can make it another way, without if, of course if it possible somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few ways this will work, however it won't be cross browser compatible.

```
$('#myOption').on('click', function(event) {
   //write code here
   alert('clicked');
});
```

Works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/crislivinitup/ckr9p/) **in Firefox only**  (jsFiddle)

1. Firefox is the **only browser** which allows the 'onclick', 'onmousedown', and 'onmousemove' events to fire on an  in a drop down list.
2. If the drop down is in the form of a list box, then the above mentioned events are supported across most browsers, **except IE**
3. Use a plugin or create a popup div as a popup menu. By doing this you can have any functionality you want, instead of being limited to the native DOM elements.
4. Otherwise use if statements

The documentation on it is very extensive at [this](http://help.dottoro.com/ljwrsipm.php) site

Comment: Yes, for me too, and in the example there is no alert too

Comment: I accept you answer, I won't use it because for me cross browser compatibility is a valuable. I don't understand point number 2, what do you mean "form of a list box", if it isn't distract you, can you describe it?

Comment: By the way, for any who will use this, in the documentation you add there is a point, which says: If you need to detect when an option has been selected or when the selection has changed in a select element, use the onchange event on the select element.

Comment: @flinth you can have drop down lists in two forms. 1. a typical drop down where if you click on it the options will appear. 2. a list box where the dimensions have been changed to allow room for all the list items to show. See here http://jsfiddle.net/crislivinitup/7QNrg/ . I just added an inline size attribute, though there are other ways.

Comment: @flinth if you liked this answer, feel free to click accept answer. Just sayin ;).

Comment: @TheWeirdNerd oh, now i see that's really work on Safari, for example:) http://jsfiddle.net/9hpJA/4/ Thanks:)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the only possible way to do this is with the `if` statement. There aren't any real event handlers for `<option>` tags.

Comment: oh, I thought it was:) , anyway thanks) I left this question open for few days, maybe somebody offer something) if not, I mark your answer as accepted:)

Comment: Why do you say there aren't any real event handlers for <option> tags? Did you test that? I got it to work by just using the id tag on the option and setting an eventListener with jQuery.

Comment: It works for me. Cross browser compatibility issues. See here: http://help.dottoro.com/ljwrsipm.php

Answer (score 0):

Just check the value after the change event:

```
$('#city').change(function (){
    if (this.value === "One City") {
        // do stuff
    } else if (this.value === "Another City") {
        // do other stuff
    }
});
```

Doing it without `if` doesn't make sense.  There is a certain level of implementation dependent behavior that takes place below the `select` element and [browsers don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119793/why-does-firefox-react-differently-from-webkit-and-ie-to-click-event-on-selec) [agree on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972280/onclick-on-option-tag-not-working-on-ie-and-chrome).  Firefox, for example, triggers a click event on an option, while Chrome does not.

Comment: He says he wants to do it without an if statement though

Comment: @TheWeirdNerd It's "another way" as requested.  Doing it without `if` doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @Dennis hmm I ask to make this without if, so your answer does not fit my question, I already made it like this but I looking for another way:), but thanks for response)

Comment: Updated my answer - I gave you a better `if` and clarified your other question with: "it's not possible"