# dynamically add buttons to a division in html css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add buttons dynamically to a division when a combobox item is clicked and I want to use the onclick() function rather than onchange() function

Here is my HTML code :

```
<div class = "row" id = "activityRow">    
    <select class="combobox" id = "activityCombobox" onclick="addButtons()">
        <option value="" selected="true" style = "display:none;">-- Choose your Activity --</option>
        <option value="val1" >Val1</option>
        <option value="val2">Val2</option>
        <option value="val3">Val3</option>
        <option value="val4">Val4</option>
    </select>
</div>

 <div class="row" id = "addonRow">

 </div>
```

Jaavascript Code:

```
var list = [];
function addButtons() {
    var e = document.getElementById("activityCombobox");
    var sel = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    var buttonName = "    ";
    buttonName += sel;
    list.push(sel);
    var funcName = sel;
    if(sel == "Val4")
        funcName = "Places";
    jQuery('#addonRow').append('<button type = "button" id = "addonButton'+funcName+'"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign" onclick = "removeButtons'+funcName+'()"></i>'+buttonName+'</button>');
}
```

This code works fine in Chrome. But when I run it in mozilla, one button is added every time I click the combobox for dropdown and another button for the selected value. So basically two buttons are added whenever I try to add one button.
I want a way to add buttons using onclick() not onchange().

Comment: sorry, is there a reason for not using onchange? which if this is not a secret?

Comment: please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119793/why-does-firefox-react-differently-from-webkit-and-ie-to-click-event-on-selec

If there isn't problem, you should use change event instead.

Comment: @webdeb actually i want to add two buttons of Val1 side by side. But onchange won't allow me to do so.

Comment: @SabyasachiBehera ok, then select is not the right if you want to use buttons.. right?

Comment: Yes. I agree. I am planning to use hover-menu now. Will that be good?