# jQuery events work in Firefox, not Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox, jquery-events

I registered some click events in my code.  They function properly in Firefox (Windows and Mac) but don't execute in Chrome (tried Windows and Mac beta).

The purpose of the JavaScript is to show the correct number of text inputs based on the value of the select element.

Here is the code: 
http://www.savetherobots.org/users/jkost/substitutioncipher.php

The script is bug-free according to [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28Firefox_extension%29).  Is something wrong with the code?

Answer (score 3):

Hai ,

For Select boxes, you need to register a handler for a "change" event rather than a "click" event. It's strange that Firefox and IE work with the click event.

Have a look at this [Click event on select option element in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402227/jquery-click-event-on-select-option-element-in-chrome)

and 
[JQuery Click event not being triggered in Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472259/jquery-click-event-not-being-triggered-in-safari)