# jquery: option plus class and click

Tags: jquery

Why does this script only work with Firefox?
How can I get it to work with all browsers?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $(".radio_c").click(function(){
        alert('message');
    });
}); 
</script>

<select name = "list1">
    <option value="dog">dog</option>
    <option value="cat">cat</option>
    <option class="radio_c" value="car_bmw">bmw</option>
    <option class="radio_c" value="car_audi">audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: i think there is something wrong with your code snippet.  The html seems to be unrelated to the javascript

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926813/jquery-events-work-in-firefox-not-chrome

Answer (score 4):

You're triggering click on an option, this is not correct. You should instead have an [onchange](http://api.jquery.com/change/) even on the select and then test the value of the selected option.

General example of what I'm saying:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("select").change(function(){
        if($(this).val() == "car_bmw") alert("blah");
    });
});
```

Comment: And if you want to simulate the original behaviour, you could use something like if($(this).find(':selected').hasClass('radio_c')) alert('blah');

Answer (score 0):

IE has no onClick event on an option
you can only use the onChange event on the select
http://api.jquery.com/change