# Submit Form for select option.onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, submit

How would I submit a form when the user clicks an option using jQuery? I found one similar question using the datepicker text input but I'm not that familiar with jQuery so I can't seem to convert it to work for a select item.

Comment: Do you have an example form? We can then give you the exact jQuery

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On `click` of an `<option>`:

```
$('option').click(function ()
{
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

On `change` of a `<select>` (this is probably the one you want):

```
$('select').change(function ()
{
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

---

As @Guffa commented:

> The `click` event on options doesn't work in all browsers. Safari for example does't trigger it.

...so you definitely want the second one.

Comment: Upvoted, but recommend double-checking that the click event fires when the user selects an option via the keyboard as well. You might need to use the change event on the select instead of the click event on the option.

Comment: The `click` event on options doesn't work in all browsers. Safari for example does't trigger it.

Answer (score 3):

The `click` event on options doesn't work in all browsers. Use the `change` event of the `select` element.

Example:

```
$('select').change(function(){
  this.form.submit();
});
```

Note that the `submit` event of the form is not triggered when you call the `submit` method to post the form.

Answer (score 1):

A small correction of these answers:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#some_link').click(function() {
        $('#form_id').submit();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#option').click(function () {
    // form validation and such then

    $('form').submit();
})
```

This is the easiest way i can think of

UPDATE:

for specific form, you can use its name or id, it really depends on how your html looks like

```
$('form[name="formnamehere"]').submit();
```

Comment: What if there is more than one form on the page?

Comment: ...or you can see [@Guffa's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131346/jquery-submit-form-for-select-option-onclick/6131408#6131408) or [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131346/jquery-submit-form-for-select-option-onclick/6131386#6131386).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select').change(function() {
  $('form').submit();
});
```

Comment: What if there is more than one form on the page?

Comment: Without HTML it is hard to give an exact script.

Answer (score 0):

I found the other answers helpful but to truly achieve what I needed of individual actions based on each option click this was exactly what I needed:

[jquery: option plus class and click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079461/jquery-option-plus-class-and-click)