# Jquery selector does not work in Safari

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, safari

I can't get the jquery selector in my javascript below to work in Safari (5.0.4):

```
$("#js-nav-bar option").click(function() {
    document.location.href = $(this).val() ;
}) ;
```

Just using `"#js-nav-bar"` as a selector works in Safari, but I need to target the `<option>` element in my HTML.

*The selector `$("option")` doesn't work in Safari either, but I do know that the jquery script is working.  My code works in FF (3.6.16) and Opera (9.27), and I've validated my HTML against the W3 validator and my javascript against JSlint.*

Is there a way I could better write my jquery selector, or could I build a compound javascript selector to work around the Safari bug?

Comment: what does the html look like?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery Click event not being triggered in Safari?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/472259/jquery-click-event-not-being-triggered-in-safari)

Comment: @contagious - I looked at the link you posted, but in a previous version of my code, .click happily targeted my <option> elements.  I've spent a day debugging, and I'm sure that the issue is with the jquery selector.

Comment: @Aliean -- see update to my answer

Comment: @Alien There is a right solution on Neal's answer. There can't be anything wrong with selectors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may have to do with the binding you're going for. Instead of binding the click event to the `<option>` itself, bind to the `<select>`'s `change` event instead.

```
$('#js-nav-bar select').change(function(e){
  var tgt = $(this).val(); // .val() should find the selected option's value for you.
  document.location.href = tgt;
});
```

See if that works any better.

Comment: `.click` vs. `.change` isn't the issue.  The issue is the jquery selector `"#js-nav-bar option"`.  In an earlier version of my page `.click` worked in Safari.

Comment: @Brad in the OP's code `#js-nav-bar` is a `div` (not a `select`).

Comment: @AlienRobert: So you're saying `$('#js-nav-bar option').css('color','#F0F');` has no effect on the items? I think you're concluding it's not working because the `<option>` shouldn't actually trigger a click event.

Comment: @Brad: I used `alert ("Hello?") ;` to debug with instead.  (If you look in my code that I posted online, you'll see it in there.)  Is that about the same thing you're asking?

Comment: @Brad - I copied your code into my script as you posted it, but I couldn't get it to work in FF or Safari.  If you want to look at the page with the change, you can see it [here](http://web.utk.edu/~bruyten/stack-test/test2.html).

Comment: @Alien he made a typo. He forgot to add `select` to the selector.

Comment: @Brad - with Karolis' fix to add `select` into your code, your solution works in Safari.  Many of you have told me to use `.change` instead of '.click` -- but that leaves me with a new issue.  If you look at my page in the top right hand corner, "Table of Contents" is the first <option> entry, but the link for that button becomes unusable unless I use `.click`.  What do you recommend if I do go with `.change`?

Comment: @Brad - also, why are you using the "e" argument variable in `change(function(e){`?

Comment: @Alien: I use e just because some browsers pass an event argument (IE) and some don't. Used to supplying it with older binding methods. -- And you want to, despite it being the pre-selected option, to be able to select the table of contents? I would add a "non-selectable" option then as the default, and force them to select the ToC.

Answer (score 2):

In your code you have `#js-nav-bar` as a div:

Try this:

```
$('#js-nav-bar select').change(function(e){ //<-- on change of the select
  document.location.href = $(this).val() ;
});
```

---

Also i noticed in your code that all you `selects` have the same class (`lim-width`), so use it!

```
$('.lim-width').change(function(){
   document.location.href = $(this).val();
})
```

Comment: Using `"#js-nav-bar .lim-width"` as my selector worked!  That provides a work-a-round for the Safari bug, but it still doesn't address why using `"option"` as a jquery selector doesn't work in Safari.

Comment: @Alien I am not sure. it is always best to put the handler on the select box in general. (the issue was also in Chrome as I did not see the alert)

Answer (score 0):

you should use the change event not the click event

```
$('.target').change(function() {
  alert('Handler for .change() called.');
});
```

Comment: two second before i posted Brad did... didn't mean to duplicate his answer